# please help me to solve $\frac{1-\exp(-10j\pi)}{1-\exp(-2j\pi)}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Why the result of the below statement is equal to $5$?

$$\frac{1-\exp(-10j\pi)}{1-\exp(-2j\pi)}$$

I compute this way and it results NaN!

$1-\exp(-j \cdot 10 \cdot \pi)= 1-(\cos(10 \cdot \pi)-j \cdot \sin(10 \cdot \pi)) = 1-(1-j \cdot 0)=0$

$1-\exp(-j \cdot 2 \cdot \pi)= 1-(\cos(2 \cdot \pi)-j\cdot \sin(2 \cdot \pi)) = 1-(1-j\cdot 0)=0$

Comment: Since $\exp(-2j\pi)=1$, the expression you are given is meaningless. It's not equal to $5$, because it is undefined.

Comment: i read it in a book and compute it by Matlab, Matlab results 5

Comment: is it a limit question?

Comment: no, this is a part of a Digital signal processing problem, which results this statement

Comment: Compensatory upvote.  I don't see much reason to downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula is $0/0$, which is undefined.  What you can do, however, is look instead at the limit of $\dfrac{1-\exp(-10 j x)}{1-\exp(-2 j x)}$ as $x \to \pi$, which is indeed $5$.

Matlab is doing numerical computations and does not have an exact value of $\pi$, so it is also in effect taking this limit.

Comment: I think you are right, thank you very much Robert :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$1-e^{-2 \pi i}=0$$ thus your term is senseless

Answer (score 0):

Expand the complex exponential function
$$
e^{i \theta} = 1 + i \theta - \frac{1}{2}\theta^{2} - \frac{i}{6}\theta^{3} + \dots.
$$

Expand about the point $x=\pi$:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\exp \left( -10 \pi x \right) &= 1 - 10 \left( x - \pi \right)i - 50 \left( x - \pi \right)^{2}+ \dots \\
%
\exp \left( -2 \pi x \right) &= 1 - 2 \left( x - \pi \right)i - 2 \left( x - \pi \right)^{2}+ \dots
%
\end{align}
$$
Take the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi} \frac
{1 - \exp\left( -10 \pi x\right)}
{1 - \exp\left( -2 \pi x\right)}
=
\lim_{x\to\pi} \frac
{1 - \left( 1 - 10 \left( x - \pi \right)i - 50 \left( x - \pi \right)^{2}+ \dots\right) } 
{1 -  \left( 1 - 2 \left( x - \pi \right)i - 2 \left( x - \pi \right)^{2}+ \dots\right)} = 
\lim_{x\to\pi} \frac
{10 \left( x - \pi \right)i}
{2 \left( x - \pi \right)i}
=
5
$$